# SQL Server 2008 - Execute sp_start_job from Insert Trigger - Does the job run asynchronously?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, database-security, sql-server-job

I wish to use **sp_start_job** to start a job from within an **insert trigger**.

The table which the insert trigger is on only has a few inserts a day atm.

The point of doing this is so that the insert trigger doesn't have to **wait for the job** to complete - is this correct?

The job sends emails to key people within the company notifying of new data.

Also, what are the **drawbacks** of this idea?

Does the login/user which is used to insert the data need any **special permissions/roles**?

Or does the job need to be **owned** by the login/user?

Does the trigger run with the login/user's permissions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can see from the output of the procedure that it doesn't send the email on the fly, it adds it to a queue so it wont lock anything by waiting the email to be sent and then continue with the trigger execution.

you can see your email log at

```
SELECT * FROM sysmail_log
```

another query that may help you is

```
SELECT * FROM sysmail_mailitems
```

Comment: Ok thanks for that clarification. But in the future, I may still wish to start a job from a trigger or stored procedure using sp_start_job - does the calling procedure have to wait for the job to complete?

Answer (score 1):

Sending email using [sp_send_email](http://EXEC%20sp_send_dbmai) is really fast.  You can call it from inside a trigger an probably lose 20 milliseconds.  Not something you'd normally need to do asynchronously.

Comment: Yeah I am right in thinking that sp_send_email actually puts the email in a queue and can complete before the email is actually sent?